# Play sound file on Timer

Tags: android

I am displaying a Timer on a screen.

The requirement is I need to play a sound every second when the timer duration is 5 seconds remaining & finally when it reaches 0 (end) , I need to play another sound.

I am using the following code:

```
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    long timeLeft = secondsRemaining // I am getting the seconds left here

   if (timeLeft <= 5) {
                playAlertSound(R.raw.beep);
            }
            else if(timeLeft == 0){
                playAlertSound(R.raw.beep1);
            }


    public void playAlertSound(int sound) {

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
```

The problem I am facing using the above code , though the each beep sound duration is less than 1 second , I am getting a continuation of the sound. I want to have separate beep sound for every second starting from the remaining 5 seconds till it reaches zero.

Also , the volume of the sound is too low.

Kindly provide your inputs , whether I need to follow any other logic ?

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure looping is disabled using the [setLooping](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29) function and for the volume issue, you can set the playback volume using: the [setVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29) function.

But, for your appliction you may want to look into using the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class instead of the MediaPlayer because it's more suitable for situations like yours when you want to play the same short sound more than once.

With your sample code, I would also reverse the order of the setting the onCompleteListener and starting playback, like this:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
    // move the mp.start() from here..        
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
          // your handler logic here..
    });
    // and add the setLooping and setVolume calls here..
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.setVolume(1.0, 1.0);
    mp.start(); // to here..
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code without the OnCompletionListener, and it worked fine with no looping? I guess I'm not understanding your problem. Also... `setVolume(1.0,1.0)` isn't correct, you need (float,float) not doubles.