# Add sound to a countdown

Tags: java, audio, javasound

How to add sound to a countdown?

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new CountdownTask(), seconds*1000);
```

Later in the program this code will activate and the timer will begin. Is there any way to make a sound file play during the countdown that ends after the timer stops?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283400/play-sound-file-on-timer

Comment: The [Java Sound Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) includes example source for playing a sound.  That example uses a `Clip` & loops continuously, but if the sound clip is 1 second long and the countdown is 5 seconds, loop the sound 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

I'd load a javax.audio.sampled.Clip with a sound, and have the timer trigger it with repeated reset & play commands. The Clip playback should be in its own thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html

Answer (score 0):

May be This is what you are looking for..

[Java AudioStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html)

**UPDATE 1:**

If you are using Java 7 you can do it easily by supported classes like **Media and MediaPlayer**

Example code:

```
String mysound = "sound.mp3";
Media hit = new Media(mysound);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Imports needed

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For downloading JavaFX plugin in eclipse use this link [JavaFX for eclipse](http://download.java.net/general/openjfx/plugins/eclipse/site.xml)

After Downloading the plugin you need to **add the JavaFX library in the build path of project.**

In configure build path go to add library and then to user library and check the check-box.

That's it!!..Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.. Also depends on what kind of application you are making

If you want to add just a beep sound in your program you can use this link:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/Beep.shtml

For adding external audio clip you can use something like this.:

```
Button logout = new JButton( "Logout" );
logout.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt )
   {
      // play a sound before loging out
      try
      {
         java.applet.AudioClip clip = 
            java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(new java.net.URL( "file:/logout.wav"));
         clip.play();

         // loging out.....
      }
       catch( Exception e ) {}
   }
});
```

Here is one online video tutorial with source code link also where you can learn to play sound in java.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ietKf_9GQ2o

Enjoy..